# Property 'user' is used before its initialization - in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I searched in google and StackOverflow about this error but I am not able to fix this error can anyone help me.

This is my **auth-service.ts** file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { User } from '../interfaces/Ilogin';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService implements  CanActivate {
  user:User;
  constructor(public loginService: LoginService, public router: Router) {}
  canActivate(): boolean {
    this.loginService.loggedIn.subscribe(next => {
      this.user = next;
    });
    if (this.user) {
      return true;
    }
   this.router.navigate(['home']);
   return false; 
  }
}
```

This is my **login.component.ts** file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LoginService } from '../services/login.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from '../interfaces/Ilogin';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  user = {} as User;
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<LoginComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any, 
    private loginService: LoginService, 
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
        mobileNumber: [''],
        password: ['']
      })
    }
    login(){
      if (this.loginForm.valid){
        this.user.mobileNumber = this.loginForm.value.mobileNumber;
        this.loginService.loggedIn.next(this.user);
        this.onNoClick();
      }
    }

  
  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

This is my **Ilogin.ts** interface file:

```
 export interface User {
    mobileNumber: string;
  }
```

This is my **login.service.ts** file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from '../interfaces/Ilogin';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
 user: User;
 loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject(this.user);
 constructor() { }

isLoggedIn(): boolean {
 console.log(this.loggedIn);
 return true;
}
}
```

**Error message I am getting:**

> src/app/services/login.service.ts:10:39 - error TS2729: Property
> 'user' is used before its initialization.
>
> loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject(this.user);
> ~~~~
>
> src/app/services/login.service.ts:9:3
> user: User;
> ~~~~
> 'user' is declared here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error come from the `login.service` because you're setting `loggedIn` with an user who is not initialized.

Try like this `loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject(null);`.

If you don't need to initialized your `user` at the beginning, you should use `Subject` and not `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: I would still use a `BehaviourSubject` - as otherwise any page subscribing after it had been emitted would not be able to get the logged in user until the next login is performed. But if it's guaranteed that everything in the apps that needs to know the logged in user has subscribed before the user is emitted you are right.

Comment: Or just `user: User = null;`. Also `ReplaySubject(1)` is usually better to use than a `Subject` to avoid headaches.